# how to merge two gsm and voip calls on android phone

Tags: android, sip, voip, gsm

I would like to know, if there is a way to merge (or maybe conference) two different calls (voip and GSM) running on android phone.

I know there is no straight forward solution to this.
There might be approaches like, getting the audio streams and merge them. This answer here suggests something like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111259/1737646

But is there any simpler way of doing this. Or, if this is the way, please provide some links to start with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

usually mobile phone OEMs buy modems from other vendors. These vendors would basically provide a modem chip + GSM stack (or LTE..) and some sort of audio engine that is tightly coupled with the hardware (dedicated DSP for codecs/voice enhancements etc).
When you are on a GSM call, the audio would be (usually) captured/played back by this audio engine sitting in modem chip.
Android would run on separate processor (APPS) and does the job of controlling the call by (some sort of standardized) APIs exposed by GSM stack.
I am not sure if there are any such standardized APIs that would duplicate the Tx/Rx streams of a GSM call and send it to APPS. So, not all vendors would provide it.
As the other link suggests, it might be available on some custom builds/phones but will not be available generically.